# Cannot install Ubuntu on UEFI device from scratch

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, 14.04, mbr

I've replaced my HDD by a SDD on my Zenbook Prime and am trying to install only Ubuntu 14.04. Before, I installed Ubuntu on the HDD which was already containing Windows 7, and everything worked great.
I've made a GTP partition table on my SSD and created 3 partitions, a boot efi one, / and /home.
When I boot, I can see grub but then after grub is complaining that it cannot find the disk by uuid.
Boot-repair doesn't work.
I've tried installing letting Ubuntu do the partitionning, same problem. I've tried disabling secure boot (which is named "anti-theft in my BIOS...) and installed in legacy mode, same problem too.

/dev/sdb is my live Ubuntu on an USB key.

Here is boot-repair log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7338302/ idea why my disk is not found?

Thanks!

Edit: I've changed the GPT table to a MBR (msdos in parted) one and created 2 partitions: / and /home.
The problem is still the same, it cannot find the disk by uuid. I've launched boot-repair, and this time, it worked, but the problem is still here.
Here is the new pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7340850/

Comment: Found this clue in your boot-repair log: WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Comment: Boot repair doesn't work with GPT tables.

Comment: It seems that it works with GPT tables, it's just that when it's trying to display a brief of what's going on, it uses fdisk and parted, but fdisk doesn't manage GPT tables.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "I've never been able to successfully repair a GPT installation with Boot Repair."

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem, even though I'm not satisfied with it:

Typing in "exit" in rescue shell... launched my Ubuntu partition.
So I added "rootdelay=90" in grub command-line, and after ~45s, grub is launching Ubuntu.

45s is "unacceptable" for me, since it's a laptop with a SSD. I will try to boot the partition other than with the UUID.

Answer (score 0):

- First click on Advanced option in Boot-repair(*not Recommended Repair*)
- Because you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode, you have to give the partition where EFI files are located. In your case it's `/dev/sda1`.
- Then run it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do that, in Advanced option, Boot-repair already found that EFI files were in /dev/sda1.

Comment: Then proceed bootrepair.

Comment: Of course I did that :) But boot-repair failed: it told me to copy/paste some lines in a terminal, then some other lines, then told me that it failed to repair the boot. Since then I've changed my partition table (see my edit) but still no chance.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the commands on terminal? If yes then post its output.

Comment: Yes. When I launched Boot-repair, I indeed launched Boot-repair. When it told me to copy/paste commands in a terminal, I did copy/paste commands in a terminal. If I'm posting here, it's because despite all that, grub is still failing to boot my Ubuntu partition. As for the commands, I'm sorry, I didn't save them. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did the commands successful runned

Comment: Why don't you try again the same? But this time don't forget the commands.